# How move focus to child window in Opera?

Tags: javascript, window, focus, opera

Opera failed with this code:

```js
var w;

$('button').on('click', function () {
  if (w && !w.closed && window.focus) {
    w.focus();
  } else {
    w = window.open('http://google.com', 'google');
  }
});
```

After we open new window and go back to parent window, we could not set focus back to child window in Opera. But other browsers work correct. Even IE. Any thoughts?

You could try this code [on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/unadat/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the option

> Preferences > Advanced > Content > JavaScript options > Allow raising
>   of windows

There is a screenshot of this preferences dialog near the bottom of this page:
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/windowresizeto.htm

Comment: Thanks, man! It's really awesome, that this option exist. I can't imagine why does Opera do that.. But I will ask this on Opera Dev.